# Is it possible to "push" messages to an active bash terminal?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu

For example to inform the user about status of some task or to report an event. This should happen not only at login but through the life of the session.
It is okay if the message display gets deferred till the user exits an application and comes back to shell.

A generic Linux solution is preferred but something that works only on Ubuntu is fine too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, some background. 
Every terminal has an associated terminal device file which you can get using the `tty` command

```
 % tty
 /dev/pts/2
```

If a program writes into this file, it will appear on the terminal. Here's an example

```
 % echo "Hi there" > /dev/pts/2
 Hi there
```

Now, whether you can write into this file or not depends on the permissions of the file

```
 % ls -l /dev/pts/2
 crw------- 1 noufal tty 136, 2 Mar  4 10:32 /dev/pts/2
```

This means that I can write into it but no one else can (which is reasonable since I don't want others to write onto my terminal). Commands like `wall` mentioned by Prashanth write into the terminal files of all the users regardless of permission since it runs with group privileges of the tty user and all the terminal device files have the same group too. Notice the `s` in the execute permission of the group below.

```
% ls -l /usr/bin/wall
-rwxr-sr-x 1 root tty 27K Mar  7  2018 /usr/bin/wall
```

Individually, you can turn on or turn off broadcasts to your terminal using the `

```
% mesg
is n
% ls -l /dev/pts/2
crw------- 1 noufal tty 136, 2 Mar  4 10:35 /dev/pts/2
% mesg y
% ls -l /dev/pts/2
crw--w---- 1 noufal tty 136, 2 Mar  4 10:35 /dev/pts/2
```

Now, to answer your question, if I write into the `tty` file of a given shell, I can display stuff into that terminal regardless of what's running there. The caveat is that you will either need to be the same user as the one running the shell or your program will have to run as sgid tty.

Here is a simple commented shell function that will display a running clock on a given terminal.

```
function dclock () {
    # Both the tput and date redirect their output to the given tty
    # file so that the display occurs over there.
    while true
          do 
              tput cup 0 50 > $1 # Position the cursor at row 0 column 50 
              date > $1 # Print the date
              sleep 1
    done
    }
```

You can open a different terminal (T), find the tty file using the `tty` command and then run `dclock /dev/pts/whatever` in your current terminal to see a clock appear in T.

Answer (score 1):

The wall command can send messages to users. 
I generally use it to notify users of scheduled Maintanence.

http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/wall.1.html